# How do i enable mobile networking by default?

Tags: 11.10, networking, broadband, usb-modem

I use a USB-Modem to connect to my PC to the Internet. But every time I connect it via USB, I have to enable mobile broadband via the networking applet on the task bar. I know it's not much work to do but i want it enabled by default so that it'll connect to the Internet automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this command to your start-up-scripts

nmcli nm wwan on

or make a longer script, if you want it to sleep before executing, like here:
[longer answer](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/modemmanager/+bug/874900/comments/12=)

Answer (score 0):

Longer answer working link below:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/modemmanager/+bug/874900